# How to ensure the user selects two date in p-calendar with prime NG

Tags: angular, primeng

I am creating a Angular project with PrimeNG which I need to select two dates in once component, for this reason I decides user p-calendar with **range** `selectionMode` .

Everything is working fine, however, the component is allowing select once date, and I dot want this, I would like the comport will allow select the two dates mandatorily.

This is my implementation:

```
<p-calendar #calendar [(ngModel)]="selectedDates" selectionMode="range" [readonlyInput]="false" [monthNavigator]="true"
              [yearNavigator]="true"  [yearRange]="1995:2050" [maxDate]="maxDate" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy" 
              placeholder="Start Date - End Date"></p-calendar>
```

Does someone know how I can make it?

I have searched in the official documentation of PrimeNg and forums, but I have no luck yet.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

In component.html file

```
<div [formGroup]="myGroup">
          <p-calendar #calendar formControlName="date" selectionMode="range" [readonlyInput]="true"  [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" [yearRange]="('1900:2016')" [maxDate]="maxDate" dateFormat="mm/dd/yy"></p-calendar>
</div>
```

In component.ts file

```
myGroup: any;
  
  constructor() { 
    this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
      date: new FormControl('')
    });
  }
```

In app.module.ts

```
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';
import { ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    CalendarModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule
  ]
```

This is working for me!